# Overlapping intervals of inputs at inputevents_mv table for same icustay_id and itemid

Tags: mimic-iii

In the following example after I discarded from rows that were "Rewritten" I still have rows (for the same drug at the same ICU admission) that their time period is overlapping. so, I want to know if the patient received several different rates of the same drug at the same time or it is an error at the data?

(to be more specific, does he received at 16:15-17:49 -> 60 ml (49+10) or just 10 ml?)

SELECT icustay_id,itemid,starttime, endtime,amount,rate,ordercategorydescription,statusdescription FROM inputevents_mv
where icustay_id=200001 and itemid=220949 and statusdescription <> 'Rewritten'
ORDER BY starttime

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is almost certainly different doses of the same compound being delivered at the same time - in this case you are looking at Dextrose 5% (`select * from d_items where itemid = 220949`). This is a very common solution for drugs so they may be receiving two different drugs both in a 5% dextrose solution. If you remove the filter on itemid it becomes obvious:

`SELECT mv.itemid, di.label, starttime, endtime, amount, rate
FROM inputevents_mv mv
INNER JOIN d_items di
ON mv.itemid = di.itemid
WHERE icustay_id=200001
AND statusdescription <> 'Rewritten'
ORDER BY starttime
LIMIT 10`

```
 itemid |       label        |      starttime      |       endtime       |   amount    |    rate    
--------+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------+------------
 225943 | Solution           | 2181-11-25 22:54:00 | 2181-11-25 22:55:00 |          50 |           
 225863 | Daptomycin         | 2181-11-25 22:54:00 | 2181-11-25 22:55:00 |           1 |           
 225158 | NaCl 0.9%          | 2181-11-25 23:47:00 | 2181-11-27 15:47:00 | 200.0000064 | 5.00000016
 226452 | PO Intake          | 2181-11-26 08:00:00 | 2181-11-26 08:01:00 |         480 |           
 221347 | Amiodarone         | 2181-11-26 11:34:00 | 2181-11-26 11:35:00 |   150.00001 |           
 228339 | Amiodarone 600/500 | 2181-11-26 12:00:00 | 2181-11-26 18:00:00 |         360 |          1
 220949 | Dextrose 5%        | 2181-11-26 12:00:00 | 2181-11-26 18:00:00 | 299.9999916 | 49.9999986
 225883 | Meropenem          | 2181-11-26 12:09:00 | 2181-11-26 12:10:00 |           1 |           
 220949 | Dextrose 5%        | 2181-11-26 12:09:00 | 2181-11-26 12:10:00 |         100 |           
 220949 | Dextrose 5%        | 2181-11-26 16:15:00 | 2181-11-26 17:49:00 | 16.45658282 | 10.5042018
(10 rows)
```

In this case you can see that Amiodarone and Meropenem are both being delivered in solutions of dextrose 5%, which are overlapping.